# APOC procedure "apoc.export.csv.query" not found

Tags: neo4j-apoc

```
CALL apoc.export.csv.query("match (m:Movie) where m.name='Matrix' return m.name","results.csv",{})
```

```
Error: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound

There is no procedure with the name `apoc.export.csv.query` registered for this database instance.
Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

- Neo4j community version 3.2.6
- plugin "apoc-3.2.3.5.jar" is already available in plugins directory.
- Windows 10 installation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure that you have added following line in `neo4j.conf` file:

   ```
   apoc.export.file.enabled=true
   ```

   - The `neo4j.conf` file in windows is located at: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition`
2. Edit and uncomment `#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins` as given below

   ```
   dbms.directories.plugins=C:/Program Files/Neo4j CE 3.2.6/plugins
   ```

   - if `#dbms.directories.plugins=plugins` is not present in your `neo4j.config` file, then you have to add this line

Comment: For those coming here with a non-Windows OS, read `neo4j.conf` file locations [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/#file-locations-locations). Usually, /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf for Linux

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that the plugin (jar file) wasn't actually in the plugins folder (on my Ubuntu `/var/lib/neo4j/plugins`). I moved the file (.jar file) (having installed as per here: https://medium.com/@niazangels/export-and-import-your-neo4j-graph-easily-with-apoc-4ea614f7cbdf) and restarted neo4j and that fixed it.

Handy Cypher command is `CALL dbms.procedures()` to confirm which Procedures are available.