# I had upgraded my neo4j dekstop from 3.3.3 to 3.3.5 , but getting compatibility issue with APOC?

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I also try to add plugin manually as suggested in [APOC procedure not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46892575/apoc-procedure-not-found)
but not nothing seems worked, please help me out. [Find screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TgQM.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like your question could use a little more information before we can help out. Could you put down what you have tried (exactly), what the environment is, what the expected result is and what the result that you got instead is? Without this information, it's going to be very hard to help you. We have more information available on what to include in a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Neo4j Desktop, when you upgrade a Project's database to a newer version, the Project's plugins are not automatically upgraded for you.

To upgrade a Project's DB version manually, you can do this:

1. Open the Project (while its DB is stopped).
2. Click `Manage`.
3. Click the dropdown arrow next to `Open Folder` and select `Plugins`.
4. Delete the old APOC jar file from the plugins folder.
5. Get the right APOC jar file version from https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases, and put it in the plugins folder.
6. Start the DB, and the APOC plugin should start running.

If the Project's UI still shows an error for the plugin, try closing the desktop and re-opening it.